# Types of property 'sections' are incompatible

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm working on an angular app. My program is working fine.

But in my spec file I'm getting the below error.

```
Argument of type '{ type: string; sections: { rjf: { type: string; text: string; depth: number; inlineEntityRanges: any[]; inlineStyleRanges: any[]; }[]; type: string; }[]; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AreasData[]'.
  Type '{ type: string; sections: { rjf: { type: string; text: string; depth: number; inlineEntityRanges: any[]; inlineStyleRanges: any[]; }[]; type: string; }[]; }' is not assignable to type 'AreasData'.
    Types of property 'sections' are incompatible.
      Property '0' is missing in type '{ rjf: { type: string; text: string; depth: number; inlineEntityRanges: any[]; inlineStyleRanges: any[]; }[]; type: string; }[]' but required in type '[SectionData]'.ts(2345)
```

This is function,   `contentDataGrouping(content: Array<AreasData>) {}` no error in ts file.

My spec,

```
  it('should group all list and accordion items', () => {
    const obj = contentService.contentDataGrouping(CONTENT_SERVICE_INPUT);
    expect(JSON.stringify(obj)).toEqual(JSON.stringify(CONTENT_SERVICE_OUTPUT));
  });
```

This is the mock which i'm sending it as input to `contentDataGrouping`

```
export const CONTENT_SERVICE_INPUT=[{type:"column",sections:[{rjf:[{type:"heading-1",text:"This is sample",depth:0,inlineEntityRanges:[],inlineStyleRanges:[]}],type:"title"}]},{type:"accordion-item",sections:[{type:"accordion-title",rjf:[{type:"heading-1",text:"This is Accordion Heading 1"}]},{type:"accordion-body",value:"accordion-body2",rjf:[{type:"paragraph",text:"This is Accordion paragraph"}]}]},{type:"accordion-item",sections:[{type:"accordion-title",rjf:[{type:"heading-1",text:"This is Accordion Heading 2"}]},{type:"accordion-body",value:"accordion-body2",rjf:[{type:"paragraph",text:"This is Accordion paragraph 2"}]}]}];
```

Below are my types,

```
export interface AreasData {
  type?: string | null;
  sections: [SectionData];
  items?: (AreasData)[] | null;
}

export interface SectionData {
  type?: string | null;
  rjf: [RJFData];
}

export interface RJFData {
  depth?: number | null;
  inlineEntityRanges?: EntityData[];
  inlineStyleRanges?: StyleData[];
  text: string | null;
  type: string | null;
  data?: any;
}
```

Please help what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: please add you test code, or a stackblitz

Comment: It is probably just a mismatch of data types. Maybe you can show us the structure of the data you are receiving?

Comment: is this `rjf: [RJFData]; correct`in `SectionData` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rjft under sections is not enclosed in [].

Either add the item to an array or change the typings to be rjft: RFJTData